# How to repeat an addition

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning Swift, and I'm stuck with a little addition system.

I set a variable for the price of a burger and also for a taco. When I click on one of those, the price appears for my selection, but if I click a second time the price doesn't add with the last one. I want to make it like a restaurant bill.

Here a little video to show it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8YvIqkAU3k

Here's the first View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sandwich: UILabel!

    var sandwichplus =  0

    var Tacosplus = 0

    var Burgerplus = 0

    var prixvaleur = 0.0

    let tacosprix = 5.5

    let burgerprix = 2.6

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        sandwich.hidden = true
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var NombreTacos: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var NombreBurger: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var Burger: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var Prix: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var Tacos: UIImageView!


    @IBAction func WantTacos(sender: AnyObject) {

        prixvaleur = prixvaleur + tacosprix

        Tacos.hidden = false
        Burger.hidden = true
        sandwich.hidden = false
        sandwichplus++
        Tacosplus++

        NombreTacos.text = " Tacos =\(Tacosplus)"
        println(tacosprix)
        sandwich.text = " Sandwich =\(sandwichplus)"
        Prix.text = "Prix =\(prixvaleur)€"

    }

    @IBAction func WhatInBurger(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    @IBAction func WantBurger(sender: AnyObject) {
        prixvaleur = prixvaleur + burgerprix

        Burger.hidden = false
        Tacos.hidden = true
        sandwich.hidden = false
        sandwichplus++
        Burgerplus++
        prixvaleur + burgerprix

        NombreBurger.text = "Burger =\(Burgerplus)"
        sandwich.text = " Sandwich =\(sandwichplus)"
        Prix.text = "Prix =\(prixvaleur)€"

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press button this code count the price `let Ajouteztacos = prixvaleur + tacosprix` where `prixvaleur = 0` and `tacosprix = 5` every time so it shows 5 for every click in both of your action so update your code like this:

First of all make your `prixvaleur` variable because it is constant like this:

```
var prixvaleur = 0
```

After that update your button action like this:

```
 @IBAction func WantTacos(sender: AnyObject) {

    prixvaleur = prixvaleur + tacosprix

    Tacos.hidden = false
    Burger.hidden = true
    sandwich.hidden = false
    sandwichplus++
    Tacosplus++

    NombreTacos.text = " Tacos =\(Tacosplus)"
    println(tacosprix)
    Prix.text = "Prix =\(prixvaleur)"

}

@IBAction func WantBurger(sender: AnyObject) {
    prixvaleur = prixvaleur + burgerprix

    Burger.hidden = false
    Tacos.hidden = true
    sandwich.hidden = false
    sandwichplus++
    Burgerplus++
    prixvaleur + burgerprix

    NombreBurger.text = "Burger =\(Burgerplus)"
    sandwich.text = " Sandwich =\(sandwichplus)"
    Prix.text = "Prix =\(prixvaleur)"


}
```

It will update the price every time you click on button.